# Extension of dominated convergence in Lieb & Loss

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In their 'Analysis' (2nd ed, p. 20) Lieb and Loss give the following extension of the dominated convergence theorem

[image: lieb-loss p 20]

I can't see why the assertion $f(x) \le G(x)$ at the end holds. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $\int |G(x)-G^{j}(X)|\mu (dx) \to 0$ implies that there is a  subsequence $G^{j_k}$ which converges to $G \,\, a.e. [\mu]$. Since $|f^{j_k} |\leq G^{j_k}$ a.e. we get $|f(x)| \leq G(x)$ a.e. in the limit.